# Android app subscription

Tags: android

I need to create app with which will use month/year subscription.(pay per month/year for app) 
Does enyone has experience or created something like this? What is best solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Market as of yet does not have auto-renewal feature so you will have to check that for yourself.
Subscription Model can have architecture.

1. Based solely on your device- This approach is suitable when you do not have to interact with outside world(using internet) eg can be games and other common apps
   Here subscription has to checked on device itself.here you an can the subscription date on device as sharedpreference or in database. and check it whenever your app starts
2. When your applcation regularly interacts with your server. eg can be newspaper apps.
   Here you can maintain device subscription status at you end by identifiying unique user/device.And check the subscription status whenever user connects to your server.

Update :

Auto Update and Renewal features have been added to In-App billing check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html)

Comment: I prefer method 2, because in 1 you can delete application data and it can be problem. Customer want method 1 so I do some research if it's possible

Comment: yes it depends on type of subsription is it like managed and unmanaged.

Comment: Are there some serverside ready solutions for in app payment? I don't want code own server payment. But some ready solution with paypal or other payment methods can be good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Since a few days, "Subscriptions" are introduced. Documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_subscriptions.html